# How can I edit shared array with two components and OnPush?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem when I am trying to share an array data object between two components with ChangeDetection OnPush.
Each of the two components can add data to the shared array with an Output event emitter.
But then the other compontent doesn't receive the update.

[Here is a working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpro2x)

When you click on button `Add1` the first time the items are added / displayed on both components. But if you click `Add1` multiple times they are only added on the first component.

app.component.html

```
<comp1 [data]="data$ | async" (addDataEvent)="addDataEvent($event)"></comp1>
<br>
<br>
<comp2 [data]="data$ | async" (addDataEvent)="addDataEvent($event)"></comp2>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent  {
data: any[] = [];  
private _data: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
data$: Observable<any[]>;
// data$ = new Subject([]);  -- also tried with Subject with same result

constructor() {    
  this.data$ = this._data.asObservable();
}

addDataEvent(data) {
  console.log("Adding Event", data);
  this.data.push(data);
  this._data.next(this.data);
}
```

comp1.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp1',
  templateUrl: './comp1.component.html',
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Comp1Component  {
  @Input() data: any[];
  @Output() addDataEvent = new EventEmitter(undefined);

  addData() {
    this.addDataEvent.next('test1');
  }
}
```

comp1.component.html

```
Comp1
<button (click)="addData()">Add1</button>
<br>
{{ data | json}}
```

comp2.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp2',
  templateUrl: './comp2.component.html',
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Comp2Component  {
  @Input() data: any[];
  @Output() addDataEvent = new EventEmitter(undefined);

  addData() {
    this.addDataEvent.next('test2');
  }
}
```

comp2.component.html

```
Comp2
<button (click)="addData()">Add2</button>
<br>
{{ data | json}}
```

Comment: @isherwood thank you for the tip. This was a really fast quick and dirty created example to share. Normally I don´t use <br> at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the actual 'object' not changing, since arrays are passed by reference, thus the input doesn't technically change so it's not updating the template. It's peculiar that the one you click updates, but that's likely because of the output event triggering a template update.

here is a working version, where the .next() is coupled with `new Array(this.data)`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egfzbu

Hope it helps, Happy coding

Comment: Oh yes your right. I am so stupid. I should have known this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the changes at the app component:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhqeke)

Comment: Thank you very much. I only can accept one answer but this works too of course